# Debugging a zero-transaction result from the transactions endpoint in customer data api

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

We use the https://financialdatafeed.platform.intuit.com/v1/accounts/account_id_goes_here/transactions endpoint on a recurring basis to fetch transactions for all of the accounts we sync.  We've been using this stably for quite awhile now, across a wide variety of accounts spanning 100s of financial institutions.  This works great.

However, occasionally we get a report from a user who claims that we're not receiving transactions that they know to exist.  Our investigation protocol is as follows:

1. To ask the user if they see the transactions when they sign into their bank's web site directly
2. To ask them to confirm that the credentials they used on their bank's web site are precisely the ones that they entered when setting up credit card sync on our site
3. We then manually inspect the response body from the above mentioned URL, to make sure that the HTTPS response indicates HTTP 200 and has a non-error response body (our app catches these errors correctly, but if debugging mysteriously missing transactions, we inspect the response body visually).
4. We look to see whether we're successfully syncing transactions for any other user that relies on the same FI. If we are, we become confident that both the bank and Intuit APIs are well-behaved, and that the problem is on our end somehow.
5. We sometimes ask users to try the same FI in Mint, guessing that if it fails in Mint, that it might be a bank or FI issue.

Investigation steps 1-2-3-4-5 tease out the root cause of at least 99% of the times when a user emails us to say that we're not successfully receiving their transactions.  However, the remaining 1% are the tricky ones.

Today I'm faced with a situation where a user sees the txns on their bank website, swears that they are using the same creds when adding the card to our site, the HTTP response from the endpoint is HTTP 200 but contains zero transactions, but yet when the user tries via Mint they successfully see transactions.

However, the particular FI (OnPoint Community Credit Union) is not one where I can do investigation step 4, because we have no other users that currently rely on that FI.  Is it possible for someone at Intuit to check to see whether there is evidence that users relying on OnPoint Community Credit Union are currently, successfully, retrieving transactions from that particular FI?

Any other suggestions for how to further deduce whether the zero-transaction response is due to: (a) user error, (b) bank server responding incorrectly, (c) Intuit server responding incorrectly, vs (d) our app behaving incorrectly?

Comment: Thanks for the great 1-5 steps. I will use this as a guideline for our troubleshooting as well.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please submit a support ticket to Intuit with the Account_ID that is missing the transactions so that we can diagnose the issue?  The first place to start when diagnosing the issue is to look at the Agg_status_code to make sure that reflects a '0'.  If we are unable to login due to invalid credentials or MFA might be a cause of the missing transactions.  I can help diagnose though once a ticket is submitted.